# open android app if installed or redirect to play store

Tags: android, jquery, mobile, intentfilter

I'm using this intent-filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data
        android:host="details"
        android:scheme="market">
    </data>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Server side like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#download", function () {
    window.open("market://details?id=com.myapp.android", ''); return false;
});
```

So whenever user click on the 'download' button, if app is installed, will ask user to open in the app. If app is not installed, will direct user to google play store.

My issue is, with this intent-filter, the scheme and host are not so specific, other apps might also use this "market://details?...." to open their download page in google play store, which will also trigger my app. So what I really want is more like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data
        android:host="details?id=com.myapp.android" <!--here I want to be more specific-->
        android:scheme="market">
    </data>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

But I found out a host like this contains  `?...` doesn't work. Wondering is there a way I can make the intent-filter more specific so that other app won't trigger it?